# How to use not equal to in sails js where clause from angular js

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

How I pass `not equal to` in `where` clause while calling SailsJS api from AngularJS.

Comment: Hello! Could you please provide a testable scenario whare your are putting angularjs and sailsjs together, show your effort so far.

Answer (score 1):

In sailsjs, according to [sails.js query language docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language), you can use the exclamation mark to effort a `not equals to` while querying an especific model. For example, consider the sailsjs model `Person`:

```
Person.find({
  name: { '!': 'Lenilson de Castro' }
}).exec(function (err, personsNotNamedFoo){
    // $scope.personsNotNamedFoo = personsNotNamedFoo;
    // or myCallBack(personsNotNamedFoo);
    // or even deferred.resolve(personsNotNamedFoo);
});
```

It basically means:

```
find all persons in `Person` where `person.name` not equals to 'Lenilson de Castro'
```

A similar scenário where aditional query option might be necessary.

```
Person.find({
    where: { name: { '!': 'foo' }},
    limit: 10,
    skip: 10
}).exec( ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles in here looking for the answer it has changed for Sails v1.x!

It's now `'!='`!

```
Person.find({
    where: { name: { '!=': 'foo' }},
    limit: 10,
    skip: 10
}).exec( ....
```